# VBA processing speed of macro

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, for-loop

I have this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Label1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

ws.Cells(3, 3).Activate

'runs a loop for active range - tests if the product on current line matched the line above and then returns a variance

Do While ActiveCell <> vbNullString
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 19

    'formatting & formulation
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12)
        .FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(SUM(IF(C" & ActiveCell.Row & "=ItemCode,ValueAmt))/SUM(IF(C" & ActiveCell.Row & "=ItemCode,KGs)),I" & ActiveCell.Row & ")"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
        .NumberFormat = "0.0000"
        .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Font.TintAndShade = 0
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With


    'clearing all but last row for each product
'   If ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) Then
'   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).ClearContents
'   End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

    'looping data
        If ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) = ActiveCell Then

            If ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7) = 0 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = ((ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value - ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Value) / ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Value)
            End If

        End If

Loop

With Columns(ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With

With UsedRange
    .Columns.AutoFit
    .Rows.AutoFit
End With

'MsgBox "run macro"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Which works as I want, which takes cost information and produces a variance line by item (if the item code matches), and a Weighted average cost.

My issue is that processing speed is very slow even with Screen updating = false. I know this has something to do with ACTIVECELL OFFSET as I know this is the slowing way to perform loops. The issue I have is that because my Formula is an arrayed formula, I have to use the .FormulaArray property and I think this is what's slowing it down.

Does anyone know a better way to re-structure this code to achieve the same /similar result? I could maybe try a Do While Loop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as the code works and OP is looking for guidance on making it quicker, it is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Please post this question there as it is too broad for this forum.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that site existed. Will know for future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from ScreenUpdating, you can also try to set the Calculation to manual before running your code.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Then once the loop is done, turn it on again:

```
Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you! Only took seconds. What does this function do ? (I've seen it before but never use it)

Comment: Normally, Excel will automatically recalculate a cell or a range of cells when that cell's or range's precedents have changed. So you just need to turn off for the meantime so that the workbook will avoid recalculate too often.